# girimi839y80904040mkrkellieimimdikiifirimKINOUBIGIAIIOVIubiuuiioioaa ufu Why do we saythat there 52 weeks in a year?

Tags: year0

Am I crazy, I've always thought there were 52 weeks in a year, a check on google returns numerous results stating the same...

But if I create a simple spreadsheet, with column A containing 1 to 365 and column B containing INT(A1 / 7) repeated 365 times, column B contains the week index corresponding to the 'julian' day in column A.

The weeks go from 0 to 52, this is actually 53 weeks.  If the 1st of January is on day 0, then the 31st of December must overlay into week 1 of the next year.

Can some help explain why we say 52 weeks and not 53?

Sorry I know this isn't strictly a coding question, but is is very relative to a lot of problems with dates and coding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming specific question, and this type of question is not what this site is all about.

Comment: 7*52 = 364; regular 365 days in a year == 52 full weeks + 1 "1 day" week, QED

Comment: We round down. There are 52.142857143 weeks (52 weeks and one day) in a year most of the time, 52.285714286 (52 weeks and two days) in leap years.

Comment: He's saying that it's confusing if we count 0th week in 0-52 but in reality we are really just saying 1 week == 7 days. Also this might belong on English SO or soemthing

Comment: I can see where you're coming from with after the 364th day we've completed 52 weeks. Then on day 365 we jump into week 53. It's just closer to floor than to ceil. Is there a specific relation to a programming problem you're referring to? Maybe context will help

Comment: The reason I posted this question is that I am working on a node.js timesheet system and was getting confused by the results of the week calculation...I found a javascript prototype adding getWeek to the date, but as far as I can tell the function is wrong.

Comment: i disagree with the sentiment that this post if "off topic" and I think the only reason why somebody would downvote this is because they haven't needed to work with precision programming of data by week. try making a multiyear series chart spanning variable number of years, grouped by week and this discussion is worthy. programming is not only strictly 'coding' all the time

Comment: According to the Excel function there are 54 weeks in the year ??? https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-weeknum-function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with the scope of stack overflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 52 **complete weeks** in a year. The year has 365 days, leaving one extra day. A leap year has 366 days, adding a second extra day. This makes 52 1/7 weeks in a normal year and 52 2/7 weeks in a leap year..

Comment: If the 1st of Jan is on day 0 and there is no leap year, then there are 365 days in the year with the last week having only 2 days, this gives 52 complete weeks of 7 days and a 2 day week...if the year is a leap year then the last week has 3 days.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you.What do you mean by saying 1st day of Jan is on day 0.(do you mean Sunday by saying 0). No matter on what day a new year starts, there will only be 52 complete weeks(7-days) if its not a leap year.

Comment: Agreed, there are 52 complete weeks and a remaining 2 or 3 days in the last incomplete week.  I've written a function now that gives a week number 1 to 53, where week 1 is always the first week that starts on a Sunday and week 53 contains the remaining days which may include the overlap into January of the next year.

Answer (score 1):

An ISO week-numbering year (also called ISO year informally) has 52 or 53 full weeks, that is 364 or 371 days instead of the usual 365 or 366 days. The extra week is sometimes referred to as a leap week, although ISO 8601 does not use this term.

The ISO week date system is effectively a leap week calendar system that is part of the ISO 8601 date and time standard issued by the (ISO) since 1988 and, before that, it was defined in ISO (R) 2015 since 1971. It is used (mainly) in government and business for fiscal years, as well as in timekeeping. This was previously known as "Industrial date coding". The system specifies a week year atop the Gregorian calendar by defining a notation for ordinal weeks of the year.

Weeks start with Monday. Each week's year is the Gregorian year in which the Thursday falls. The first week of the year, hence, always contains 4 January. ISO week year numbering therefore slightly deviates from the Gregorian for some days close to 1 January.

Comment: source: [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)